# How to properly convert an array string of 'numbers', using a cipher of letters?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'll get to the point. I know this should be simple, but is giving me the runaround.
I am working on a secure local network. I need to take an input (in my case, an IP address) And cipher that address before storing it safely in a database.

I'd like to cipher it into a letter format. Hard to explain, but if you view this code, you should see what I'm trying to accomplish. I've formatted it to accept an input from you, the user, whereas this function will be called in real time in the background when it's working properly.

Ideally, the user would input `12.23.34.45`

The function would print `KS.SL.LE.EI`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 16

void cwitch(char *instr[MAXLEN]){
    char *nstr = "0123456789";
    char *cstr = "DKSLEIANQP";

    int count = strlen(instr);
    char *output[count];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(instr[i] != '\0'){
            int t;
            for(t = 0; t < count; t++){
                if(instr[i] == "."){ /*Do Nothing, Straight Logic - I Know This Is Useless*/ }
                else if(instr[i] == nstr[t]) output[i] = cstr[t];
            }
        }
    }
    output[count] = 0; //Null Terminate The String
    printf("Output: %s\n", output);
}

int main(void){
    char *input[500];
    printf("Enter Address: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0; //Remove \newline Character

    cwitch(input);
    return 0;
}
```

However, upon execution, I'm clearly not getting the desired results, or I wouldn't be here!

```
[root@RyM ~]# ./test
Enter Address: 12.23.34.45
Output:
         `
[root@RyM ~]# ./test
Enter Address: 167.174.12.178
Output:
[root@RyM ~]# ./test
Enter Address: 45.223.6.1
Output:
         `
[root@RyM ~]# ./test
Enter Address: 918.6.56.222
Output:
[root@RyM ~]#
```

Any help/advice is appreciated. I'm new into C. Expect warnings when compiling this. Feel free to roast/advise me, pertaining to said warnings existence.
Edit: Warnings included below

````
[root@RyM ~]# gcc -o test Test.c
Test.c: In function ‘cwitch’:
Test.c:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/string.h:399: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
Test.c:19: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Test.c:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Test.c: In function ‘main’:
Test.c:31: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdio.h:626: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
Test.c:32: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/string.h:399: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’```
````

Comment: Should your first step not be to get rid of those (unlisted) warnings? Maybe your problem solves itself, then.

Comment: I have attempted to, however I was hoping that advice would be given here pertaining to them, as I personally do not know other ways of completing this task, which would heed no warnings. I will edit the post to include the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is a wrong definition of char array (or const string).
A correct definition would be:

`char output[count]; // where count is compile time constant`

and NOT `char *output[count];`

the `[]` tells the compiler this is an array (which is a type of pointer).

Thus, no need to use `*`, unless you want to define an array of pointers (which is not your case).

here is a cleaned-up code: *** Note: this code is far from being perfect or even good, I merely made small changes in order to make it compile and work. ***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 16

void cwitch(const char* instr) {
    const char* nstr = "0123456789";
    const char* cstr = "DKSLEIANQK";

    int count = strlen(instr);
    char output[MAXLEN];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (instr[i] != '\0') {
            int t;
            for (t = 0; t < count; t++) {
                if (instr[i] == '.') {
                    output[i] = '.';
                }
                else if (instr[i] == nstr[t]) output[i] = cstr[t];
            }
        }
    }
    output[count] = 0; //Null Terminate The String
    printf("Output: %s\n", output);
}

int main(void) {
    char input[500];
    printf("Enter Address: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0; //Remove \newline Character

    cwitch(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! And yes, this was just to see if I can actually store/cipher a "string" of numbers this way. I also see the advantage of declaring constant chars, and appreciate you fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
void cwitch(char *instr[MAXLEN])
```

you are saying that `cwitch` accepts an *array of character pointers* (of `MAXLEN` length). It should just be `char *instr`. Similar, in this line

```
char *output[count];
```

you are declaring an *array of `char *`*, while you intend it to be an array of `char`: `char output[count]`. Finally, you cannot compare a character `'x'` to a *string*

```
if (instr[i] == ".")
```

-- it must be a character literal again (`'.'`).

A small logic problem: if the input character is `.` you must not "do nothing", you must copy it to the output string as well.

With these fixes your program actually works.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I also was aware of the string literal. Something I looked over this early morning. Thank you for your clarifications! I have some reading on arrays and pointers to do!